# Multiple REGEXREPLACE matches to remove characters from a URL in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following string, I am looking to use multiple regex matches with REGEXTRACT to just leave me with the full URL.

`/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2F`

**REQUIRED RESULT**

https://www.amazon.com

I have removed the prefix to give me the URL with

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"uddg=",REPT(" ",255)),255))
```

resulting in

*https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2F*

Then using a REGEXREPLACE function to leave me with

*https//www.amazon.com%2F*

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D5, "%3A%2F%2F", "//")
```

So I then combine these to make:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(D2,"uddg=",REPT(" ",255)),255)), "%3A%2F%2F", "//")
```

How can I add another match to REGEXREPLACE to remove the %2F string on the end as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do with a single `REGEXREPLACE`:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^.*(https?).*(www\.\w+(?:\.[a-z]+)+).*$","$1//$2")
```

---

Update:

Based on OP's comments, he could go with (depending on the string):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^.*?(?:%2F){2}(.*)%2F$","//$1"))
```

Or even:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(D2,"%2F"),3)
```

Comment: This is better, however I have found out when I try and make the URL into a link with the HYPERLINK function, it adds an additional http to the front of the http/https:// - Is there a way strip out the http* part? (So this ```/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2F``` always comes out) - Plus if there is no www it doesn't output properly

Comment: As I mentioned before, it's a bit hard without proper samples. You just included one. Maybe you then need `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^.*?(?:%2F){2}(.*)%2F$","//$1"))` @sigur7

Comment: Please see in a Google Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DbGc1oyELDgMOHxzrqExX0fG3_b7n99Pz7A6vy1tlvc/edit?usp=sharing - if required, you can File-Make a copy to have a play

Comment: So remove the two forward slashes @sigur7. And depending on your string, you may be able to use `=INDEX(SPLIT(D2,"%2F"),3)`